# Recovery root password in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I forgot administrator password in a Kali Linux install. Is it possible to recover the root password from another administrator user account?

Comment: Yes, go to a command prompt and type `sudo passwd <admin account>` to change it. Is there something more to this?

Answer (score 2):

You say this; emphasis mine:

> I forgot **administrator password** in a Kali Linux install.

Then you say this; emphasis again is mine:

> Is it possible to recover the **root password** from another administrator user account?

Is the issue with the “root” user? Or another user on the system that has `sudo` rights?

So if there is another user with `sudo` rights on the system they can do this to reset the password of any specific user; including an administrator:

```
sudo passwd [name of user]
```

If you want to reset the “root” user password, just run the same command but with “root” as the name of the user:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Answer (score 0):

default login for kali linux is , root and password: toor

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does not answer the original question.